# Python: sort the list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort the array c. But I don't get the answer a,b,c,d. Instead I get a,b,d,c. What could I do, for sorting the whole array and not only one row?

EDIT: I want to sort the numbers. And the connected letters, should have the same order like the sorted numbers. sorry my question wasn't clear. Maybe I should join number and letters first. Like this:
[['a',1]['b',2]....

```
a = ['a','b','d','c']
b = [1,2,4,3]
c = [[],[]]
c[0]=a
c[1]=b
c[1].sort()
print(c)
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort `a`, based on the corresponding values in `b`?

Comment: Because there seems to be some confusion what you want to achieve I suggest adding an example of the output you expect.

Comment: are you trying to to sort the array c[0] according to the values in c[1]?

Comment: Yes I am trying to sort a, based on the corresponding values in b. Sorry.

Comment: you should be sorting c[0] then, not c[1]

Comment: You should stop storing multiple related attributes in separate lists, where attributes are linked only by their respective positions in each list.  Use tuples or define a class and use instances of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> a = ['a','b','d','c']
>>> b = [1, 2, 4, 3]
>>> c = zip(a, b)
>>> c
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('d', 4), ('c', 3)]
>>> c.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> c
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a look at what's going on here:

```
# Initialize the lists
a = ['a','b','d','c']
b = [1,2,4,3]
c = [[],[]]

# Assign the lists to positions in c
c[0]=a
c[1]=b

# Sort b, which was assigned to c[1]
c[1].sort()
print(c)
```

So, of course you could not expect `a` to get sorted.  Try this instead:

```
# Sort a, which was assigned to c[0]
c[0].sort()

# Sort b, which was assigned to c[1]
c[1].sort()
print(c)
```

Or if `c` is of variable length:

```
# Sort every list in c
for l in c:
    l.sort()
```

**Edit**: in response to your comment, the letters are not connected to the numbers in any way.  If you want them to be connected, you need to join them in a structure like a tuple.  Try:

```
>>> c = [ (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (4, 'd'), (3, 'c') ]
>>> c.sort()
>>> print c 
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')]
```

By default, tuples will sort on their first element.  Note that you could use any letters here in place of a, b, c, d, and the tuples would still sort the same (by number).

Comment: Now I see the problem. Maybe I should join the number and the letter at first.

Comment: when I sort the numbers, the connected letters should join too.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be what you really want to do:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'z', 'd', 'c']
>>> b = [1,   2,   4,   3]
>>> c = zip(a, b)
>>> c
[('a', 1), ('z', 2), ('d', 4), ('c', 3)]
>>> import operator
>>> c.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
# this would be equivalent: c.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> c
[('a', 1), ('z', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

Comment: but now he sorts the letters. I want to sort the numbers.

Comment: kame: Sorry about that, fixed now; I see you've edited the question to be clear on that point, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
[sorted(x) for x in c]
```

Comment: Of course it does. It just doesn't work the way you think it does. It returns a new list containing sorted lists.

Comment: okay, but i want to sort the numbers. and the connected letters. should have the same order like the numbers. sorry my question wasn't clear.

Comment: please see above, I get the solution

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind for me on this is to use the numpy array, rather than the builtin `list` datatype.

Something like:

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> a = array(['a', 'b', 'd', 'c'])
>>> a.sort()
>>> print a
['a' 'b' 'c' 'd']
>>> reshape(a, (2,2))
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'd']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: I think that's a bit of overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sort_parallel(a, b):
    ba = zip(b, a)
    ba.sort()
    return [e[1] for e in ba]

a = ['a','b','d','c']
b = [1,2,4,3]

print sort_parallel(a, b)
```

prints

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try (for Python 3.x):

```
def sort_a_based_on_b(a, b):
    c = sorted(list(zip(b, a)))
    return list(list(zip(*c))[1]) # Returns the sorted a
```

This returns the sorted a, based on the values in b.

```
a = ['a','b','d','c']
b = [1,2,4,3]

print(sort_a_based_on_b(a,b))
```

Prints `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Answer (score 0):

In Python, an `array` (of the sort you are using) is called `list`. As for your problem, change `c[1].sort()` to `c[0].sort()` and your list of strings will be sorted instead of the list of ints contained in c[1].

Comment: but I want to sort the numbers. -- array --> list ! okay

Comment: Oh, I guess danben's answer has solved it for your now :). And I just pointed out the array vs. list thing because the term array is used in Python to describe another, less flexible but faster, container (http://docs.python.org/library/array.html).

Answer (score 0):

Roger Pate gave a good answer, but you said "but now he sorts the letters. I want to sort the numbers."

Here is a modified version of Roger Pate's answer that sorts c by the numbers.  Is this what you want?

```
>>> def mykey(tup):
>>>     return tup[1]
>>>
>>> a = ['a','b','d','c']
>>> b = [1, 2, 4, 3]
>>> c = zip(a, b)
>>> c
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('d', 4), ('c', 3)]
>>> c.sort(key=mykey)
>>> c
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

The "key" to the `sort()` method function is a function.  The function returns the key you want to use.  The `mykey()` function takes a tuple and returns its second value (value indexed by 1).  Thus, `.sort()` will sort using the number part of the tuple.  And the strings will still match the numbers.  You could even split the list `c` again to recover lists `a` and `b`, and they will still match.

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide the custom comparison function for sort to use.using lambda it is pretty simple:

```
cmp = lambda x,y: (x[1], x[0]) < (y[1], y[0])
L.sort(cmp = cmp)
```

Lambda is all anonymous function, in this case it reverses the order of elements, such that second element becomes primary key, and the comparison is done using "<" operator.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
>>> a = ['a','b','d','c']
>>> b = [1, 2, 4, 3]
>>> c = zip(b, a)
>>> c.sort()
>>> c = [(y, x) for (x, y) in c]
>>> print(c)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```